# Carriage return in perl

Tags: perl, carriage-return

```
while(<FILE>)
{
    if (/progress/)
    {
        my @msgs = split(': ',$_);
        print "$msgs[1]";
        sleep 1;
    }
    local $| = 1; # to clear the buffer
    print "\r"; # carriage return
}
```

I am reading from the `<FILE>` for percentage progress, and print on the screen with carriage return but this doesn't seem to be working. Any idea or alternate way?

Answer (score 1):

Because `$msgs[1]` ends in a newline. `chomp` what you read from `FILE`.